# Android + JMockIt Integration

Tags: android, unit-testing, jmockit

Has anyone successfully integrated JMockIt Unit tests while Mocking Android objects?

For example

If I do something like

```
@Test
public void contextTest(@Mocked Context context) {
...
}
```

Just by having the mocked context, it seems JMockIt causes a class rewrite error.

Would be great if someone has an example snippet showing everything is working fine.

Comment: I've tried this and had no problems using JUnit 4.11 with JMockit 1.12 and Android api 19 jars

Comment: JMockIt actually reports an issue on their github with roboelectric integration

Comment: Ah, ok, I wasn't using Roboelectric :-)